# How to call dynamic(SELECT) stored procedures in ASP.Net Web API

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I want to call dynamic select SP in Web API. It doesn't work for below SP.

dynamic select SP like

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE uspCalcuateSalesSummaryDynamic2
                 @returnAverage bit,
                 @shipDate int AS 
DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(4000),
        @parameterDefinition NVARCHAR(4000),
        @function NVARCHAR(10)

IF (@returnAverage = 1) SET @function = 'Avg'
ELSE SET @function = 'Sum'

SET @parameterDefinition = '@shipDate int'
SET @statement =
    'SELECT   SOD.ProductID,' +
              @function +  + '(SOD.LineTotal) as Result' + @function + '
     FROM     Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD
              INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHEader SOH
                         ON SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID
     WHERE    YEAR(SOH.ShipDate) = @shipDate
     GROUP BY SOD.ProductID'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @statement, @parameterDefinition, @shipDate
```

It's working for plain Select SP.

If any one can help me than it's good for me.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not helpful, what have you done so far, what exact problem are you facing, what error messages are you getting? Details matter

Comment: It doesn't give output when I use SP with given format(string format), but It's working with SP without string format(if single quotes removed)